# Assign a hex value to the low nibble of a byte

Tags: ruby, encoding, hex, byte, nibble

I am doing an integration and I have the following condition for a field:

> If the length of the data is odd, the low nibble of the last byte is assigned the value hex 'F'. This hex 'F' for padding ensures that a whole number of bytes are used for the field and is not included in the length of the item.

I tried appending the hex F, but this is wrong:

```
data << "%X" % 15
```

I suppose I need to get the last byte and perform some magic on it, probably some bitwise operation:

```
low_nibble = data.bytes.last.get_low_nibble
low_nibble = transform_low_nibble_to_hex
data << low_nibble
```

I will be glad if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary representation of `0xF` is `0b1111`. Conveniently, this is all `1`s, and an easy way to ensure a bit is `1`, is to `OR` it with `1`. So, an easy way to ensure all the bits in a nibble are `1` is to `OR` the nibble with `0b1111` / `0xF` / `15`.

Accessing a single nibble is usually inconvenient, but thankfully, there is also an easy way to ensure that a bit stays what it was: `OR` it with `0`. Therefore, in order to ensure that the first nibble of the byte stays what it was, we need to `OR` the first nibble with `0b0000`, and to ensure that the last nibble is `0xF`, we need to `OR` it with `0b1111`.

Put that all together, we need to `OR` the entire last octet with `0b00001111` / `0x0F` (which is just `0b1111` / `0xF`):

```
data.bytes.last |= 0xF
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, very well explained, I think I grasped the general idea. Unfortunately at the moment I cannot test this, however I will give it a test tomorrow, hopefully this is the solution I need.

Comment: I tested it today, had to apply some adjustments on my side, but the core logic was the one you explained here. Thank you!